# Short story involving music composer and a musician playing the history of music

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, music

Narrator is a music composer. He’s describing the experience of his friend, a musician, after some transformative (lightning strike?) event. Subsequently the musician plays a history of music and this becomes a popular sensation. He takes the show on the road.

Eventually the reader discovers that the narrator is recounting this story from backstage at one of his friend’s concerts. And in the course of playing the history of music, the musician starts playing a tune that sounds familiar to the narrator. Narrator then realizes it is a song that he himself is in the process of writing! And when this musician friend gets to the moment in the piece where the narrator has gotten to in writing it, the musician pauses… and then completes the playing of the as-yet unwritten piece.

Comment: Update: ChatGPT says “The short story you described is titled "The Composer." It was written by Michael Scott in his collection of short stories called "The Stories of Michael Scott." But I can’t find this book anywhere. Anyone know where to find it?